# Problems loading 3d model within my hosting

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I have uploaded a web page to my server which utilises three.js.

My web page works perfectly on my local machine. However when I uploaded my web page to my server, my 3d model is not loading! What am I missing or doing wrong?

This is the code that I use to load my 3d model:

```
textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    map = textureLoader.load('img/CHRIS.jpg');
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
    loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load( 'obj/CHRIS3.obj', function ( object ) {
      canvas.css('background','none');
      object.traverse( function ( node ) {
        if ( node.isMesh ){
          node.material = material;
        }
      });
      scene.add( object );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my .obj file permissions were wrong. I fixed the issue by changing the permission on the .obj file to 755